# Free Proxy service

Tags: proxy, reverse-engineering

http://ultrareach.com is the free proxy service I use to access the web.  Its comes in two parts: the client and the service.  Is there any way that I can dissect the client to see whether it uses any type of standard protocol to connect to the servers?  I would like to be able to access the *service* from another *client*, specifically one that would run on linux.  Now, depending on how you look at this, it might not be programming related, but I think that, depending on the solution, it could be.

Answer (score 1):

Use Wireshark to see what's happening at the network level.

Comment: Do you think you could give me some pointers in how to use it and what to look for in terms of clues to what protocol it uses?  THanks.

Comment: Just run it, and it will figure out what protocol is being used - it'll almost certainly be a standard one. One useful tip for using Wireshark is Right-click / Follow Stream.